# jqPlot graph with zoom for 31 days

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to create a graph with 31 days of data and then with zoom on i want to be able to zoom in on the days eg 7 days if i were to highlight 7 days.

The problem I have is i want the labels on the x axis to start at the first day and the last one to be the last day but jqPlot seems to add days on for some reason.

For example with my data below it starts the x axis with 21 and the last one is 26 but i want it to show each day from 22 to 23.
I tried using min and max but only one worked.

I would also like it to show each day 1,2,3,4 etc instead of 1,5,12,19 etc as it currently does.

I also noticed when you zoom in sometimes it has 3,4,4,4,5, 5, 5, 6 etc i always want it to each day.

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        s1 = [["6/22/2012",425.32], ["6/23/2012",424.84], ["6/24/2012",417.23], ["6/25/2012",390],
            ["6/26/2012",393.69], ["6/27/2012",392.24], ["6/28/2012",369.78], ["6/29/2012",330.16], ["6/30/2012",308.57],
            ["7/1/2012",346.45], ["7/2/2012",371.28], ["7/3/2012",324.7], ["7/4/2012",315.07], ["7/5/2012",300.36],
            ["7/6/2012",315.76], ["7/7/2012",292.96], ["7/8/2012",310.02], ["7/9/2012",359.36], ["7/10/2012",372.54],
            ["7/11/2012",386.91], ["7/12/2012",449.15], ["7/13/2012",444.25], ["7/14/2012",463.29],  ["7/15/2012",510.15],
            ["7/16/2012",467.86],["7/17/2012",467.86], ["7/18/2012",481.32], ["7/19/2012",537], ["7/20/2012",546.43], ["7/21/2012",567],
            ["7/22/2012",544.62], ["7/23/2012",573.2]];



        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
            title: 'test',
            series: [{
                label: 'test',
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
            }],
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,

                    tickOptions:{formatString:"%#d"}
                },
                yaxis: {
                    // renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{
                        formatString:'$%.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            cursor:{
                show: true,
                zoom: true,
                constrainZoomTo: 'x'
            }
        });
    });
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out by adding numberTicks as well as the min & max:

```
xaxis: {
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    min: '6/22/2012',
                    max:   '7/23/2012',
                    numberTicks: 31,
                    tickOptions:{formatString:"%#d"}
                },
```

It fixes the issue with the extra days and also the zoom is working perfectly now